# Basic electrical circuit loops

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

Hi I have a basic electrical circuit and I am trying to make loops.

Those things on *IMG-2*.

[image]

[image]

I just don't understand how are they made.

Why are the *"one square loops"* only in upper squares and not down too. If you have any source with this how it is made please share or if you have time to explain it.

Comment: the lower loops are redundant, as is the outer square, since they are the differences of the main loops shown

Comment: It appear that you are trying tom apply Kirchoff's loop law.  this law is applicable to any loop.  you can start with whatever loops appear to be easiest to solve

Comment: Thanks know i understand it more. Going to google  Kirchoff's loop law :)

Comment: I think you'll get better results googling "Kirchhoff's Voltage Law" than Kirchhoff's Loop Law.

Comment: Is it correct the devices with one circle are voltage sources and the two circles overlapping are current sources? (Americans use different symbols so this won't be obvious to many readers)